# Retrieving list data from MailChimp using Ruby and gibbon

Tags: ruby, gibbon

I've created a test list in MailChimp and I added 2 subscribers.

I created a Ruby script that will retrieve emails of all subscribers with the help of `gibbon gem`.

The problem is that I'm the beginner in Ruby and I'm still really not confident with syntax.

Here's the code

```
require 'gibbon'
require 'byebug'

def mailchimp
  gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key:"my-api-key")
  gibbon.timeout = 10
  gibbon.lists("my_list_id").members.retrieve
end

debugger
mailchimp
```

When I test this in debugger with `mailchimp.body`, I can see that I get response, but it's in hash and with tons of information, while I only need to get email_address.

How can I dig or loop through this hash and only return email_address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the request to only the fields you'd like to see. Only retrieve emails for fetched lists:

```
response = gibbon.lists("my_list_id").members.retrieve(params: {"fields": "members.email_address"})
```

With that response body you can call `keys` to see what fields are available to you. A little less noise than printing out the entire body in IRB.

---

[Related section in the Gibbon Docs](https://github.com/amro/gibbon#fields)

Comment: How to fetch multiple fields of specific member? like email and id?
I tried `gibbon.lists(list_id).members(member_id).retrieve(params: {"fields": "email_address, id"})` but it doesn't worked